# When I use plone.api content.create in for find results ever empty

Tags: python, plone, plone-4.x

I use `plone.api` to create a script to upload a batch of PDFs into a folder, the information about which folder I'll put each PDF come from csv. And my problem is..

If the next value interartion in `for` bring the same year, that was created in the last interation of `for` a var `yearBrain` have a output empty again. And when the script is finished, in plone I will have a lot of folder with the title `2015` and ids `2015`, `2015-1`...

```
for i in csv:
    yearBrain = api.content.find(context=container, SearchableText=str(i[1]))
    if solidData(yearBrain):
        #solidData returns if exist infor and year have 4 digits
        print 'if true, insert a PDF into a folder'
    else:
        #If solidData false, yearBrain results empty, so create a folder
        container = api.content.create(type='Folder', title=unicode(str(i[1]), 'utf-8'), container=container)
        transaction.commit()
```

I think that `api.content.find` can't find a recently created folder.

How I solved this problem?

[UPDATE - WORKS]

```
        if pdf_tipodoc:
            if pdf_tipodoc == 'PROCESSO':
                valor = splitProcesso(pdf_nprocesso)
                # valor returns a list with two elements like ['234', '2016']
                container = portal[plone_site_pasta][processos]
                # Container is: <ATFolder at /intranet/ged/processos>
                print container.objectIds() #look what have inside!
                if valor[1] in container.objectIds():
                    print 'Folder already created! Commit PDF inside'
                else:
                    container = api.content.create(type='Folder', title=valor[1], container=container)
                    transaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use api.content.find for this: you don't need a search for looking for an item with know id inside a folder.

If `i[1]` is someway your current year (I guess), just try something like:

```
if str(i[1]) in container.objectIds():
    # year folder already exists
```